# How to adjust size and delay of variable info popup window in debug mode in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am wondering if there's a way to adjust the default size of the popup that is shown when hovering a variable in Eclipse debug mode. It's quite small, and when inspecting the contents of an object graph that e.g. contains lists, I have to adjust the window's size each and everytime.

Also, is there a way of decreasing the delay time that has to pass until the window is shown when hovering an element?

Answer (score 4):

You can select the variable by double clicking the name and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to bring up a window. And after you adjust the window to the size you like, the size will be remembered so that you will see the same size window when you inspect another variable next time. 
But this is not a "popup window", you'll need to use keyboard to bring that up every time.